# How to get or consume data from a variable returned by a service in angular 9?

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, observable, var

I have tried many ways to get the data of this variable, it should be noted that I am starting in Ionic 5 and angular 9.

In my ** authentication.service.ts ** I have the following:

```
 export class AutenticationService {
  userData: any;
  constructor(
          public afStore: AngularFirestore,
          public fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
          public router: Router,
          public ngZone: NgZone,
          private Navega: NavController
  ) {
      this.fireAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }
    });
  }

  SignIn(values: any) {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email.toLowerCase(), values.password).then(
        res => {
          resolve (res);
        },
        err => reject(err));
    });
  }
```

In the ** login.ts ** I have the following

```
    export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
      validationsForm: FormGroup;
      errorMessage = '';
      successMessage = '';
      valores: any;
      logo = '';
      constructor(
        public authSrv: AutenticationService,
        public router: Router,
        public loading: LoadingService,
        private menuCtrl: MenuController,
        public frmBuilder: FormBuilder,
        public alert: AlertasService,
        private navega: NavController
      ) { }
      ngOnInit() {}
      logIn(values: any) {
        this.loading.present('Iniciando...');
        this.authSrv.SignIn(values)
          .then((res) => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            this.validationsForm.controls.password.setValue('');
            this.navega.navigateForward(['/dashboard']);
          }).catch((error) => {
            localStorage.removeItem('user');
            this.loading.dismiss();
            window.alert(error.message);
          });
      }
```

in the ** dashboard.ts ** is the problem to consume the data of the userData variable: any

```
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {
Username: any;
  constructor(
        public authSrv: AutenticationService,
        private menuCtrl: MenuController,
        public Navega: NavController,
        public loading: LoadingService

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
    this.Username = this.authSrv.userData;
    console.log(this.authSrv.userData);
  }
```

the ** `console.log (this.authSrv.userData);` ** prints ** undefined **, but when looking in the browser I see that in the loclstorage if the data is there, to the store. What I want to get is the ** displayName ** of the variable ** Username **.
Please help.

Comment: You may want to try this: put in a debugger statement before this code,  this.userData = user; in authservice. Now press F12, and run your application. How many times is this breakpoint hit?

Comment: Hello, in the debug three impressions of the service appear, I noticed that the first time I log in the variables of the dashboard.ts Username and this.authSrv.userData throws undefined, but when closing and logging in again it shows the values in those variables it is as if I had printing before they have value.

the other question would be how to capture the data in the console.log displays data to me like this:

Comment: `P {N: Array(0), l: "AIzaSyCbasOcmRP5xeVZrEp2vyt_vDtQwOWu8WI", m: "[DEFAULT]", s: "app-badda.firebaseapp.com",`    and I need to get the displayName from this array, `this.Username.displayName` no found

Comment: Ok it's what I thought. Your service is being loaded three different times. Also, I don't see an array in your print out. It looks like an object. Is your service using@injectable?

Comment: I only have the @injectable ({providedIn: 'root'}), How could I solve the problem that loads twice, 1 load when I do the login, and in the dashboard it also loads to access data?

Comment: Take out provided in root

Answer (score 1):

thanks  **John Peters**, for the hint on injectables
I have solved the problem that my service is running multiple times on my components put the following:
**login.page.ts, register.page.ts, dashboard.page.ts**
`constructor (
    @Inject (AutenticationService) public authSrv) {}`

and in the debug it only appears that it runs once.
**The second problem is still not solved**, the dashboard comes to me **userData** in the console.log shows me the following and I want to extract the email and displayName.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxSpD.png)